# array out of bounds exce.. creating multidimensional array from mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I've been trying to create a `String[][]` extracting its items from a database using `JDBC` but haven't been able to get the results into `String[][]` what am I doing wrong I get this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at modelo.ConectorBaseDatos.getRows_From_DB(ConectorBaseDatos.java:194)
    at modelo.ConectorBaseDatos.main(ConectorBaseDatos.java:237)
```

line 194 is:

```
rows_list[rows][cols] = result.getString(2);
```

Here is the code:

```
public String[][] getRows_From_DB(String tableName, String db, String querY){

            try{

                    int columnCount = this.getTableInfo(tableName, db, true, false) - 1;
                    int rowCount =  this.getTableInfo(tableName, db, false, true) - 1;

                rows_list = new String[rowCount][columnCount];

                Connection con = getConnect_to_DB("fifa");

                PreparedStatement statement  = con.prepareStatement(querY);

                ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

                while(result.next()){

                         for(int rows = 1; rows <= rowCount; rows++){

                                for(int cols = 1; cols <= columnCount; cols ++){

                                        rows_list[rows][cols] = result.getString(2);
                                        rows_list[rows][cols] = result.getString(3);
                                        rows_list[rows][cols] = result.getString(4);
                                        rows_list[rows][cols] = result.getString(5);
                                }
                         }
                }




            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en getRows_From_DB()" + e, "ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
            }

    return rows_list;
}
```

Comment: Java arrays start at 0 and go up to their defined index - 1. You're trying to access the element at the defined index (rowCount).

Answer (score 2):

A couple problems, here:

- You start indexes with 1 instead of 0 (as mentioned by Kon)
- You set given rows_list[rows][cols] 4 times (which 3 times will replace the instance)
- You double iterate through rows (one as returned in the result set and 2nd time when using row count.

See below for the solution addressing those issues:

```
  ...
  ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

  int rowNumber = 0    
  while(result.next()){
     //Alternatively iterate here in another loop through all columns.
     rows_list[rowNumber][0] = result.getString(2);
     rows_list[rowNumber][1] = result.getString(3);
     rows_list[rowNumber][2] = result.getString(4);
     rows_list[rowNumber][3] = result.getString(5);
  }
}catch(Exception e){
  ...
```